# Jekyll on Heroku build succeeds but page cannot be served

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, jekyll

Following some blog posts, I have this configuration. The site works locally, and the heroku build is successful, but when I go to the url it says *Application Error*. Any ideas of why this configuration is not showing my site?

Gemfile

```
ruby '2.0.0'    
gem 'foreman'
gem 'jekyll'
gem 'rack-contrib'
gem 'rack-jekyll'
gem 'rake'
gem 'thin'
gem 'eventmachine'
gem 'jekyll-sitemap'
```

_config.yml

```
exclude: ['config.ru', 'Gemfile', 'Gemfile.lock', 'vendor', 'Procfile', 'Rakefile']
```

config.ru

```
require 'rack/jekyll'
require 'yaml'
run Rack::Jekyll.new
```

Procfile

```
web: bundle exec puma -t 8:32 -w 3 -p $PORT
```

Rakefile

```
namespace :assets do
  task :precompile do
    puts `bundle exec jekyll build`
  end
end
```

Heroku build log

```
-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Using set buildpack heroku/ruby
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rack
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.9.7
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
       Using rake 10.4.2
       Using colorator 0.1
       Using daemons 1.2.3
       Using eventmachine 1.0.8
       Using ffi 1.9.10
       Using thor 0.19.1
       Using foreman 0.78.0
       Using git-version-bump 0.15.1
       Using sass 3.4.19
       Using jekyll-sass-converter 1.3.0
       Using rb-fsevent 0.9.6
       Using rb-inotify 0.9.5
       Using listen 3.0.4
       Using jekyll-watch 1.3.0
       Using kramdown 1.9.0
       Using liquid 3.0.6
       Using mercenary 0.3.5
       Using rouge 1.10.1
       Using safe_yaml 1.0.4
       Using jekyll 3.0.0
       Using jekyll-sitemap 0.9.0
       Using rack 1.6.4
       Using rack-contrib 1.4.0
       Installing rack-jekyll 0.4.3
       Using thin 1.6.4
       Using bundler 1.9.7
       Bundle complete! 8 Gemfile dependencies, 26 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Bundle completed (1.87s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Precompiling assets
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Configuration file: /tmp/build_908302d35b2d2195bffc55d1ffca43c9/_config.yml
       Source: /tmp/build_908302d35b2d2195bffc55d1ffca43c9
       Destination: /tmp/build_908302d35b2d2195bffc55d1ffca43c9/_site
       Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
       Generating...
       done in 1.264 seconds.
       Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
       Asset precompilation completed (1.97s)
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> web
       Default types for Multipack -> console, rake
-----> Compressing... done, 58.2MB
-----> Launching... done, v9
       https://yodel-website.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: Do heroku logs have any information ? `heroku logs --tail`

Comment: I got it to work by deleting my Procfile and instead using `web: bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RACK_ENV -p $PORT`

Comment: Now that you mention it, your Gemfile did not include the puma gem....

Comment: Good call, I noticed that too. but still no luck when I added it :(